# Finding the fundamental solution of a system of $N$ coupled second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In solid state physics one encounters a differential equation of the form
$$\forall n\in\{1,2...N\}: m\frac{\partial^2 \delta_n(t)}{\partial t²}=\kappa(\delta_{n-1}(t)+\delta_{n+1}(t)-2\delta_n(t))$$
with the boundary condition $\delta_n(t)=\delta_{n+N}(t)$.

What method does one use to find the **complete** solution to this coupled system of differential equations?

---

In physics textbooks this equation is often solved by making the Ansatz $\delta_n=\Re\left(a\exp(i(kn-\omega t))\right)$ with $0\le\omega$ by convention. This Ansatz solves the equation iff
$$\omega=2\sqrt\frac{\kappa}{m}\left|\sin\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right|\quad\textrm{(dispersion relation)}$$
Enforcing the boundary conditions gives a quantization of the parameter $k\phi$
$$\exp(ink)\overset{!}{=}\exp(i(n+N)k)\rightarrow k_j=j\frac{2\pi}{N}, j\in\mathbb{Z}$$
It is not necessary to include all $j$ values though. All distinct solutions of the form of the Ansatz are found if one includes $-N\le j\le N$ ([Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)). As can be best seen by observing
$$\exp(in k_{j})=\exp\left(inj\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)=\exp\left(in(j\textrm{mod}N)\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\exp\left(inmN\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)=\exp(in k_{j\textrm{mod}N})$$

But how does one gurantee that all solutions are a superpositions of the solutions we found and the solution space is not any larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ansatz is based on writing $\delta_n(t)$ as it's Fourier series. So as long at that assumption is valid, you have the solution. If the function is continuous, and is bounded (does not diverge to infinity), then  the [Dirichlet conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) assure you that this is the only solution, since the Fourier transform is unique.